# Basic Authentication v/s Token Based Authentication Security

Tags: authentication, jwt, access-token, bearer-token, refresh-token

Throughout internet its explained that one must use Token Auth(JWT, refresh) for any type of API related authentication. But still I have some concerns in using Token based authentication:

1. With token based authentication also, first time we have to use credentials to get a token, so if anyone is able to get this generated token from response, then hardly matters that in subsequent requests a password is sent using basic auth for next API call or a token is sent for the same, as server will validate both of them.
2. If token expiry time is reduced then also a refresh token or refresh token API will be there to generate new token for another subsequent requests. So here also if someone has this refresh token captured from the very first request then hardly matters we are using basic or token based auth process.
3. Its being said that token can be validated without the use of database interaction & will be faster to validate, but in case of single device login availability logic (means user can login to 1 device at a time, if login to other one, then should be logged out from previous device / browser), we have to go to database every time to check whether user is using same device or another one. (As in this case with some logic, we will have to keep device identity in the database, or if we save our token in database on login then if user login from other device, new token will be generated & older device will not match its token from database, so we can logout user from the old device).
4. As far as safety is defined in documents for token based authentications, we have seen cases that when user click any link, his/her account(like fb, li, google, etc.) get hacked or transactions made from his/her bank account without his/her knowledge, & this all happens with renowned platforms who works with this token based authentication, so what is big deal with basic auth with all these same type of concerns ?

May be I am asking these questions because of lack on knowledge, please comment on my queries so I would be able to correct myself.

I tried to explain my concerns & expecting comments that helps me to understand & use things in more better way that I may not aware of...

Thanks.

Comment: "_Throughout internet its explained that one **must** use Token Auth(JWT, refresh) for any type of API related authentication._" - No-one is saying that.

Comment: "_As far as safety is defined in documents for token based authentications, we have seen cases that when user click any link, his/her account(like fb, li, google, etc.) get hacked or transactions made from his/her bank account without his/her knowledge, & this all happens with renowned platforms who works with this token based authentication, so what is big deal with basic auth with all these same type of concerns_" - This is utter nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

> Throughout internet its explained that one must use Token Auth(JWT, refresh) for any type of API related authentication.

No-one is saying that. You don't *need* to use a Bearer-token authX scheme to secure a web-service.

There are other approaches that enable both client authentication and server-side authorization checks on the client's requests, such as using [signed requests](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-cavage-http-signatures-12), [client certificates](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/client-certificate-authentication-part-1/ba-p/324623), and platform-provided methods like [Kerberos](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/157630/kerberos-iis-authentication-over-http)/[Integrated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication) Auth - also consider network-level security that doesn't depend on application-layer security, such as [IPSec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec).

> With token based authentication also, first time we have to use credentials to get a token, so if anyone is able to get this generated token from response, then hardly matters that in subsequent requests a password is sent using basic auth for next API call or a token is sent for the same, as server will validate both of them.

This isn't a problem in practice because communication happens only over secure channels (i.e. HTTP-over-TLS), thus eliminating the possibility of secrets (such as Bearer tokens) being intercepted. For example, [OIDC *absolutely requires* TLS](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#TLSRequirements).

There are also systems that also support insecure channels, and they use nifty things like [Key Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange) to allow secrets to be exchanged over an insecure medium. And schemes that use preshared secrets and/or prior established trust relationships can use that knowledge as the basis for secure communications when a platform-provided TLS connection isn't available, [such as SSH](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4252).

> If token expiry time is reduced then also a refresh token or refresh token API will be there to generate new token for another subsequent requests. So here also if someone has this refresh token captured from the very first request then hardly matters we are using basic or token based auth process.

Not necessarily:

In OAuth2/OIDC's case specifically, a `refresh_token` is *only* used when a client can keep a secret secure: so this is often used with server-to-server communications, or from clients that have some way of securely storing data (e.g. a hardware enclave or TPM-backed encryption), but it is not used with web-browser based clients (like Angular or React SPAs) because web-browsers have no way of securely storing secrets.

Additionally, a `refresh_token` isn't necessarily like a bearer-token either: some schemes use single-use refresh-tokens, so in the surprisingly-unlikely event that a refresh-token is intercepted and used by an attacker then the legitimate client would notice as soon as they tried to use it [and can revoke it](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/refresh-tokens/revoke-refresh-tokens). I'll admit this is a mitigation rather than a protection scheme, but it does demonstrate that refresh-tokens aren't as big a security liability as you'd think.

Another protection is to tie the refresh-token to some connection fingerprint - such as requiring all refresh-token requests for a given user session to use the same ISP or geographical IP range as used when the user began their session and to block the request if a request comes from an unexpected place. Also, rememeber that refresh-tokens are only used with clients actually capable of storing secrets, which includes things like non-user-specific `client_credentials` and related schemes (like signed-requests) which are often required in order to use a refresh-token, so even if someone does intercept a refresh-token in-transit they couldn't use it because they wouldn't be able to capture the client's secrets used to make signed requests (doubly-so if they're using a TPM to sign requests).

Overall, I notice your concerns all assume that a refresh-token can be easily intercepted or captured - and I would share your concerns if it were that easy - *fortunately it isn't*.

> Its being said that token can be validated without the use of database interaction & will be faster to validate...

This is true and is why that approach is used in massively-scaled globe-spanning web infrastructure such as Google's services, Microsoft [Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-oidc), and others.

As these schemes use self-contained, self-describing structured tokens containing claims/assertions (like OIDC with JWT and SAML) it means they get the **huge** advantage enabling RPs (Relying Parties, aka Web Services) to be stateless, which enables massive scaling: it means you can use tens or hundreds or more servers to load-balance a Web Service - you can't do that with stateful schemes (which would require load-balancer host affinity which hurts performance) - and fault-tolerant: the IdP service could become totally unavailable but everything else would still work until `access_token` expires.

> but in case of single device login availability logic (means user can login to 1 device at a time, if login to other one, then should be logged out from previous device / browser) we have to go to database every time to check whether user is using same device or another one.

What you're describing is not a good system: it won't scale nor could feasibly work as part of a distributed-system.

Also, restricting users to being on a single device at a time is kinda... pointless? Why would anyone want to do that? (I do appreciate concerns about wanting instant logout on shared devices, like Internet Cafe PCs, but that can be done without restricting users to only being on one device at a time.

> As in this case with some logic, we will have to keep device identity in the database, or if we save our token in database on login then if user login from other device, new token will be generated & older device will not match its token from database, so we can logout user from the old device

There are **many** problems with what you're describing there... as far as both usability and performance are concerned: users today *expect* to be able to use services from multiple devices concurrently (e.g. I have Slack on my phone and desktop open at the same time) - and performance would be abysmal: it means **every** request will incur a [hit to the single database table](https://www.ibm.com/docs/ssw_aix_72/devicemanagement/hotspotmgmt.html) you're storing token copies in - and also means you can't be using a distributed system because different nodes/services/etc can't all access a private singleton database which *also* becomes a critical single point of failure.

Furthermore, because this idea of yours depends on *mutating* a single value (the last-generated-token) for each user it means you can't use a scalable database that uses eventual-consistency, but will have to use a traditional row-locking-and-blocking database - and it won't be fault-tolerant: if your database goes down then your entire system goes down because not-only will you not be able to issue new tokens for new sessions but you won't be able to lookup the token on every request as you suggested: *everything will break*, whereas with, for example, OAuth2, the client and other RPs can operate independently of the IdP.

> As far as safety is defined in documents for token based authentications, we have seen cases that when user click any link, his/her account(like fb, li, google, etc.) get hacked or transactions made from his/her bank account without his/her knowledge, & this all happens with renowned platforms who works with this token based authentication, so what is big deal with basic auth with all these same type of concerns ?

That is utter nonsense.